# How to make re-usable zod validator in react?

Tags: reactjs, zod

## Background

I'm making signup form with zod and react-hook-form.

```
const imageValidator = (z: any) => {
    return z
        .instanceof(File)
        .optional()
        .refine(
            (file?: File) => {
                if (!file) return false;
                return file.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE && ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(file.type);
            },
            {
                message: "Item photo: Only .jpeg, .jpg, .png files of 2MB or less are accepted",
            }
        )
        .refine((file?: File) => {
            if (!file) return true;
            return ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(file.type);
        });
};

const referenceValidator = (z: any) => {
    return z
        .instanceof(File)
        .optional()
        .refine(
            (file?: File) => {
                if (!file) return false;
                return file.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE && ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(file.type);
            },
            {
                message: "Item photo: Only .jpeg, .jpg, .png files of 2MB or less are accepted",
            }
        )
        .refine(
            (file?: File) => {
                if (!file) return true;
                return ACCEPTED_REFERENCE_TYPES.includes(file.type);
            },
            {
                message: "References: Only PDF, DOC, HWP, JPG, PNG, PPT, XLS, ZIP file types are accepted",
            }
        );
};

const submitSchema = z.object({
    org_name: z.string().min(1, { message: "Please describe the applicant company/organization." }),
    contact_name: z.string().min(1, { message: "Please enter your contact name." }),
    org_manager_name: z.string().min(1, { message: "Please enter the name of the representative." }),

    // Item photo, required
    image1: imageValidator(z),
    image2: imageValidator(z),

    // Reference, optional
    reference1: referenceValidator(z),
    reference2: referenceValidator(z),
    reference3: referenceValidator(z),
});
```

## Problem

```
const imageValidator = (z: any) => {
    return z
        .instanceof(File)
        .optional()
        .refine(
            (file?: File) => {
                if (!file) return false;
                return file.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE && ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(file.type);
            },
            {
                message: "품목 사진: 2MB이하의 .jpeg, .jpg, .png 파일만 허용됩니다",
            }
        )
        .refine((file?: File) => {
            if (!file) return true;
            return ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(file.type);
        });
};
```

What is the type of `z` ?
How to avoid `any`?